# Rails 3 ActionMailer - no recipent address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

i have a problem with my prod actionmailer. I'm hosted on site5 sharing cloud. The problem is i get this error message.

```
A message that you sent using the -t command line option contained no
addresses that were not also on the command line, and were therefore
suppressed. This left no recipient addresses, and so no delivery could
be attempted.

------ This is a copy of your message, including all the headers. ------

Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2011 21:06:42 +0000
From: noreply@mydomain.com
To: myemail@mydomain.com
Message-ID: <4e750be27b3ef_4a9c159402ee91b039763@themailserver.com>
Subject: test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

i added default

```
default :recipient => 'noreply@mydomain.com'
```

but the mail return me the same error.

my ActionMailer controller

```
class Emailtousers < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "noreply@mydomain.com"
  default :recipient => "noreplay@mydomain.com"
  def plan_notification(resource)
    @resource = resource
    puts resource
    mail(:to => "myemail@mydomain.com", :subject => 'test')
  end
end
```

What i missed?

i followed this to help me http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: please try it with a recipient that is outside that domain and let us know what you get

Comment: The Recipient are the to: mail? i've tried with another domain and another email, and the default from get the same mail.. no recipient messages. Thanks

Comment: Yes, recipients are the ones that get the email.

Comment: ok, i get the same thing! My host told me to change authentication => :login to :plain, but same thing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this problem using the :sendmail delivery method with exim. Adding this to config/application.rb fixed it for me:

```
config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = { :arguments => "-i" }
```

I found the solution at https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/70#issuecomment-2639987

Comment: thanks, i resolved this issue .. the problem was on server side. not properly mail setting. But thanks for this fix. i will try it with my next rails projets.

Comment: @neimad could you please share the solution you found for this issue?

Comment: @neimad: yes, please, as Robin said... I could also only work this around with Steve's solution, and feel quite puzzled why.